# Does radius server returns Access-reject on key mismatch?

Tags: key, protocols, return-value, radius, mismatch

Does the radius server returns Access-reject on key mismatch between client and server , or does it drop the packet .  I was not able to get as , does this part comes in packet verification process?

Comment: Is there any code involved with this question? If no, then migrate to serverfault.

Comment: Thank you. Its does not have code . I will post this on serverfault.